# JavaFX Drag and Drop Phases

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

JavaFX Drag and Drop Phases:

1. Source: onDragDetected
2. Target: OnDragOver
3. Target: onDragDropped
4. Source: onDragDone

Can I do something after phase 3 on source side? (Source and Target is different applications). For example: I want unpack file from archive after **onDragDropped** and transfer this file to Target.
How can i do it?

Comment: Have you found an answer on that?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

`setOnDragDropped(...)` literally happens just after you finished the drag&drop gesture. There is nothing after that, except of course the notification which is sent to the source for `setOnDragDone(...)`.

Why can't you unpack your file in `setOnDragDropped(...)`? This seems to be the perfect place to do so

Comment: Second is not my application.